# How to Improve Web Development Using Virtualization in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, virtualization

Improving Web Development Using Virtualization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20090207084158/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com:80/articles/102908-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Virtualization is, in essence, creating multiple miniature (virtual) PCs inside of your primary PC. One of the great benefits of this is that it allows you to isolate and test an application or set of applications in an environment that is free of other things to interfere. It used to be that in order to get a new machine with a new development environment on it you had to have another piece of hardware, or you had to rebuild your system to the new environment. With virtualization, you simply install the new environment that you need into one of the virtual machines and you run it as necessary. When you're done you can shut it down.

Virtualization is the ultimate in isolation -- it can allow you to do things on one piece of hardware that are simply not possible without it. For instance, you can install software in a test environment on a member server because it won't run on a domain controller. You simply fire up two virtual machines at the same time -- one being the domain controller and the other being the member server. Both virtual machines can run on the same physical hardware at the same time without either being aware that they are sharing a machine. The result is a quick way to implement testing environments.

Virtualization technology allows for the virtual systems to be frozen in place. In other words, the exact spot in the machine that you are at can be frozen for an indefinite period of time. If you work on one project until it's released and stable and need to come back in a year and start working on it again, you can freeze the system when you stop working on the project and then restart it a year -- or more – later. When the system is restarted it will be like time had not passed. The system will be restored exactly as it was left.

This particular feature is great for developers who support multiple systems including consultants who have different clients with different projects that they will have to support over time. You don't have to worry about recreating an environment to test a bug fix; you simply thaw out your virtual machine and go.

Virtualization programs have a feature described as Undo disks. Undo disks allow you to operate on the system and if you decide that you don't want to save your work you simply don’t' accept the changes in the undo disks. Poof. Like magic everything that you did is undone and it's like it never happened.